# Bus error in memory read/write operation

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I hav written a kernel program for memory read/write operation.

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/io.h>

static uint32_t *mem_alloc(void)
{
   uint32_t *base, *mem;
   base=kmalloc(5*sizeof(uint32_t),GFP_KERNEL);
   mem=ioremap(base,5*sizeof(uint32_t));
   return(mem);
}

static void mem_write(uint32_t *memory)
{
  uint32_t *mem1;
  mem1=memory;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    *mem1=0x1010F0F0;
    mem1++;
  }
}

static int __init insert(void)
{
  uint32_t *memory;
  memory=mem_alloc();
  mem_write(memory);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit remove(uint32_t *memory)
{
  kfree(memory);
}
```

in this program a bus error occurs when executing the instruction

```
 *mem1=0x1010F0F0;
```

Comment: Why is there no parameter in the call to mem_write inside insert?? Did you copy-paste the code into StackOverflow, or did you retype it by hand?

Comment: there is no compilation error in the code. memory allocation is correct i debugged but i dont understand why bus error occurs during the assignment   *mem1=0x1010F0F0.

Comment: ioremap is platform-specific. What documentation or code sample are you using? What does it say?

Comment: i m using powerpc platform SoC.

Comment: OK, but you must have read some documentation or code sample about this platform. Help us out by pointing us to it...

Comment: ioremap() is a function which returns virtual addresses. i got to know it from the chapter "getting hold of memory" from the book "Linux Device Drivers" by Alessandro Rubini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ioremap() is used to map the bus memory into the CPU space.

**ioremap** performs a platform specific sequence of operations to make bus memory CPU 
   accessible via the readb/readw/readl/writeb/ writew/writel functions and the other mmio helpers. **The returned address is not guaranteed to be usable directly as a virtual address.**

**kmalloc** allocate the memory in contiguous memory location in physical memory and returns it's virtual address pointer.

**ioremap expects the physical address in input**, **but you are giving the virtual address as physical address to ioremap**.That virtual address value may same as the physical address value of the any of bus and it was mapping that physical bus space to virtual (and we have to access the device registers using readb/readw/readl/writeb/writew/writel), because of that it was   giving error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I find as a reference for ioremap:

> void* ioremap  (unsigned long  phys_addr,
>                  unsigned long  size
>        )
>
> Remap I/O memory into kernel address space.
>
> Parameters:
>    phys_addr  begin of physical address range
>    size  size of physical address range
>
> Returns:
>   virtual start address of mapped range
>   Here no real mapping is done. Only the virtual address is returned.

Looks like it maps a hardware device address into virtual memory, not a memory block allocated from *real* memory.

Comment: how can we access memory block from kernel

Comment: @vijayaraj - I'm not a kernel expert, but if you get memory from kmalloc and your code is in kernel mode, I guess you should just use the returned pointer.